# Dimension under integral local homomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> Let $f:(R,\mathfrak m) \to (S,\mathfrak n)$ be an integral local homomorphism. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $R$ not equal to $\mathfrak m$. I want to know if one can claim $\dim S/f(\mathfrak p)S\neq0 $.

This is true when $(f(\mathfrak p)S)^c=\mathfrak p$, but in general?
Thanks.

Comment: There is a non-maximal prime lying over $p$, hence yes.

Comment: Thanks, why "hence yes"?

Comment: $P\cap R=p\implies pS\subseteq P$ and since $P$ isn't maximal we have $P\subsetneq n$.